# Is libpq more like a JDBC driver or JavaSE's java.sql package?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, libpq

Is it correct that the following two are different concepts:

- a JDBC driver (e.g. a JDBC driver for PostgreSQL) and
- JavaSE's java.sql package?

Is it correct that the JavaSE's java.sql package is an API built upon a JDBC driver, to become driver-agnostic?

In C for PostgreSQL,

- what is the equivalence to a JDBC driver, and
- what is the equivalence to java.sql?
- Is [libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq.html) more like a JDBC driver for PostgreSQL or JavaSE's java.sql package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java SE' `java.sql` package defines interfaces that Java libraries called JDBC drivers can implement to provide the functionality of working with a database in a way that's [almost] vendor agnostic. With JDBC (the `java.sql` package), you [almost] never use vendor-specific classes, and just program against the interfaces.

libpq is something completely different - it's a [c](/questions/tagged/c) library that's completely specific to [postgres](/questions/tagged/postgres). It makes no claim and no attempt to be a generic interface to program against any RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks. Does a JDBC driver directly implement a DBMS-specific API or the DBMS-agnostic JDBC API? I guess it is the former?

Comment: @Ben JDBC drivers usually implement a DBMS-specific transport protocol (e.g., [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/protocol.html)), and expose an [almost] DBMS-agnostic interface for the programmer (e.g., implementing `java.sql.Statement`).

Comment: So there is nothing standing between a JDBC driver and JDBC API, because a JDBC driver has already implemented JDBC API i.e. java.sql?

Comment: @Ben that very much depends on the implementation. Modern day drivers are usually pure-java implementations without any component in the middle.

Comment: Since a JDBC driver has already implemented JDBC API i.e. java.sql, when writing a Java program, can we just `import` a JDBC driver instead of  `import java.sql`? (I know the latter can reduce dependency on specific JDBC driver, and just want to know if it is possible to do the former)

Comment: @Ben Why don't you **try doing** that instead of asking questions that can be self-answered by experimentation?

Comment: I am not very familia with Java yet. @Mark

Comment: @Ben in theory, you can write a program completely with concrete types (e.g., form Postgresql's driver) and not directly use the interfaces from `java.sql`, but I can't think of a single good reason to do that.

Comment: @Ben You may want to consider learning the basics before asking esoteric questions.